# Grant users, roles, groups access to KMS key

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I would like to give access to everyone (users, roles, groups) in an AWS account access to a KMS key using a **YAML** that can be read uploaded into **CloudFormation**. How would this code be modified to allow this to happen? I have included the root account for clarity (- 'arn:aws:iam::############:root'). I do not want to list each user, group or role individually.

Thank you.

```
Resources:
  key:
    Type: 'AWS::KMS::Key'
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: "Devkey"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                - 'arn:aws:iam::############:root'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
  SSGSKeyAlias:
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Alias"
    Properties:
      AliasName: !Join [ "/", [ alias, DevKey ] ]
      TargetKeyId:
        Ref: key
```

Answer (score 3):

When you grant access to the root account like you've done, that allows you to manage access using IAM ([docs reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam))

Once this is done, you can create IAM policies and assign to users/groups/roles that permit access to the KMS keys.

Helpful reading would be the KMS documentation on [using kms key policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-overview)

Answer (score 2):

Here.. Got it to work.

```
Resources:
  key:
    Type: 'AWS::KMS::Key'
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: "Devkey"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '##AccountNumber##'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
  SSGSKeyAlias:
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Alias"
    Properties:
      AliasName: !Join [ "/", [ alias, DevKey ] ]
      TargetKeyId:
        Ref: key
```